# Footer stuck in middle only when there is little content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, gatsby

I know the title is a known 'issue'. However, I have tried many solutions, but none seem to work.

My footer is stuck on the bottom (phew) on almost all cases (when there is a lot of content, when I can scroll,..). Sadly, when there is barely any content, it just goes straight to the middle. I really have no clue why this is happening :( I am using Gatsbyjs for my website.

This is the `global.css`

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: whitesmoke;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #2b2b2b, #414141);
}
```

My `footer.js` component and it's css is:

css:

```
footer {
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  position: relative;
  font-size: smaller;
  opacity: 0.98;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

html for footer:

```
 const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <footer>
        <p>©Copyright {currentYear} Humital - Made with ❤️</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

the main html comes from `layout.js`:

```
<div className={styles.flex}>
    <NavBar />
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <main>{children}</main>
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
```

Which holds some css for the container:

```
    .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.flex {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Not sure why the footer won't go down when there is no content :( Any help is welcome! :)

Comment: put `min-height: 100vh;` to body, you might see a slight strange behaviour in Safari mobile but it should be 98% there for you. A question though, why do you wrap main and footer with divs?

Comment: Yea, this + adding the min view to my flex container seemed to work! I did remove the divs. You're absolutely right, they don't need to be there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add `min-height: 100vh` rule (and a `flex-direction`) to your `.flex` class:

```
.flex {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Because your `.container` has the `flex: 1 0 auto` will push the footer to the bottom.

Summarizing, you only need this rules to stick your footer to the bottom:

```
.flex { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

`.flex` applies to the outer wrapper, which contains the `Footer`, the `<main>` and the `<NavBar />`.

`.container` applies to the `<main>` or the `<main>`'s wrapper. I think it's not needed to wrap the `<main>` with another `<div>`, you can apply the styles directly to the `<main>` tag, yet the approach to push the footer to the bottom is exactly the same.

Comment: Adding the min-height worked!! However, I now have this in my .js :

 `<>
      <div className={styles.flex}>
        <NavBar />
        <main>{children}</main>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </>`

With this in the CSS:


 `.flex {
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
`

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Nothing anymore ^^ It works perfectly fine now! Thank you for your help! I really appreciate it <3